# Why are rows being overwritten in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, web-scraping

I am running the below code that grabs the same information from multiple URLs.

```
data = []

alldata = soup.find_all(class_='module show-times')

for item in alldata:

    each_race = item.find_all(class_='racing-time')

    for item in each_race:
        racelinks = item.find_all('a')

        for a in racelinks:
            link = (a.get("href"))

            full_url = urljoin(url, link)

            driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()

            driver2.get(full_url)

            html2 =driver2.page_source

            soup2  = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')

            data=[]

            for item in soup2:

                verdict = soup2.find_all(id="oc-verdict")

                for item in verdict:
                    first = item.find_all('span', class_ ="beta-footnote")[1]
                    odds_first = first.nextSibling
                    odds_first_simple = odds_first.replace(',', '')

                    second = item.find_all('span', class_ ="beta-footnote")[2]
                    odds_second = second.nextSibling
                    odds_second_simple = odds_second.replace(',', '')

                    third = item.find_all('span', class_ ="beta-footnote")[3]
                    odds_third = third.nextSibling

                    data.append({
                        "Favourite": odds_first_simple,
                        "Second": odds_second_simple,
                        "Third": odds_third
                        })


            df = pd.DataFrame(data)
            print(df)
```

The code gets the info as designed however I am trying to create a `dataframe` of all the info scraped from all of the URLs. When running the above I get the output here which just overwrites the previous row with the most recently scraped data instead of adding to the previously scraped data:

```
             Favourite               Second              Third
0  Here Comes Georgie   Beneficially Yours   Cracking Rhapsody
   Favourite        Second             Third
0  Blue Fin   Fia Fuinidh   Five Dollar Fine
   Favourite       Second         Third
0  Lisloran   R S Ambush   Bushmill Boy
```

I am looking for the output like this where each new line is added:

```
             Favourite               Second              Third
0  Here Comes Georgie   Beneficially Yours   Cracking Rhapsody
1  Blue Fin             Fia Fuinidh          Five Dollar Fine
2  Lisloran             R S Ambush           Bushmill Boy
```

I have tried moving the `append()` bit around and `concat()` but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question lacks some details, here is just an approach that assumes that `data` is a list to which further dictionaries are correctly added - take the creation of the `dataframe` out of your loop.

###### EDIT

Based on your additional added information it is still the same issue with creating the `dataframe` inside your loop and in addition overwriting `data` inside the loop. There should only be one `data` outside the loop.

```
...
data = []

alldata = soup.find_all(class_='module show-times')

for item in alldata:

    each_race = item.find_all(class_='racing-time')

    for item in each_race:
        racelinks = item.find_all('a')

        for a in racelinks:
            ...
            for item in soup2:
                verdict = soup2.find_all(id="oc-verdict")
                for item in verdict:
                    ...
                    data.append({
                        "Favourite": odds_first_simple,
                        "Second": odds_second_simple,
                        "Third": odds_third
                        })

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: I have added the full code now in the hope that helps but if there are any more details I can provide to help then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it this way too but the only output I get is the very last entry to the dataframe and not a full table. Any ideas at all please?

Comment: Do you really have deleted the second `data = []`?